# CSS: Can't see what is causing this gap

Tags: css

At [this page](https://www.whitewreath.org.au/white-wreath-can-help/), I can't see what is causing the black horizontal gap between `#wapper`, and `#main`:

[image]

I can't any margin on `#wapper` or `#main` and can't see any child element of `#wapper` or `#main` with margins causing this gap.

Comment: you want to fully remove black gap?

Comment: Yes I do @sagarkodte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to remove fully black gap just removed below code from css

```
#main {
padding: 1px 0 !important }
```

add this.
there is **#content-wide** it's taking **10px margin** if your remove this margin from #content-wide the background-image effect will hide so in this case you have to add more padding to #main.

Comment: Thanks. I've set `#main`'s padding to 0 and the gap remains.

Comment: Thanks, that fixes it. Update your answer please?

Comment: padding: 1px 0 !important add this to #main and adjust gap increasing or decreasing 1px to onwards.

Comment: So why 1px worked while 0px didn't? There's still a pixel line.. May be try -1px? (@Steve?)

Comment: because  there is #content-wide it's taking 10px margin that's why @yakovL and Steve

Comment: if your remove this from #content-wide the background-image effect will hide so in this case you have to add more padding to #main

Comment: @Steve, so since sagar's answer brought you the final result, I guess you should accept the answer

Answer (score 2):

You have a `?` between them.

```
      <!-- .content (end) --> 

    </div>
    <!-- #header (end) -->
    ?
<div id="main">
```

Remove that and the gap goes away.

Comment: Ahh. Thanks. I've removed the `?` and the gap has reduced but not disappeared...?

Comment: @Steve remove the padding in your [#main]

Comment: I don't see any gap anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the `?` symbol, you probably have to remove all the white-space between these elements.

Comment: Thanks. I've removed the white space between `#wapper` and `#main` and the gap remains.

Comment: @Steve Do you know why your `#main` and `#header` (not sure about `#wrapper`) and some other elements have `position: relative`? Try setting `position` to `static` everywhere (although I don't see `top` set to anything in any of those elements).

Answer (score 1):

Remove margin-top for content-wide as in below code

```
#main #content-wide {
    width: 940px;
    margin: 0 10px 10px;
}

or

#main #content-wide {
    width: 940px;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Could you please approve answer if this is what you wanted?